Eth tx state error: tx state and trace state is not matched..!
I found a case where the data is different while looking at the eth tx data and trace data.
Why is this happening??
Isn't this a problem?
case 1) tx succeeded, but error message is displayed in trace.
The error message says there is not enough gas, but the tx was successful.
Also, I can't see trace data in etherscan.
tx : https://etherscan.io/tx/0x03d15392f4f774d0dbf8dff287991896cf39b171fb0b1da6c51d9045657a0cc9
trace data:
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'error': {'code': -32000, 'message': 'first run for txIndex 85 error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address 0x0b92619DdE55C0cbf828d32993a7fB004E00c84B have 1414044108792614043 want 1414044806692614043'}}
case 2) tx is successful, but trace records that it was reverted
As far as I know, the status of tx and the top state of trace are the same for success and failure.
But here, they are different. Isn't it an error?
Looking at the tx function, it seems to be a function related to eigenlayer. Will it have an effect?
tx: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4a73a881ca8e9e2f83ef99025c9258e48a6e7bb16c6f7b05d5216fcfa4cac504
trace: https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x4a73a881ca8e9e2f83ef99025c9258e48a6e7bb16c6f7b05d5216fcfa4cac504&type=parity#raw
Case 1 has been found only once, but case 2 is found often.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x95b56a0b9d19a78bec3a3a652227a254fd97422a08730a8433693d23fbc4d952
https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xc42eea14117746b62ac3a859687630d90c992047cb7140a4139f793c89e159f3&type=parity

